# How to send raw data in a POST request Python

Tags: python, post, python-requests, postman

Body I'm trying to send:

```
update_request={
        "id": "f07de0a44c2911ea8fb2bc764e10b970",
        "user": {
            "user": "3491574055045",
            "timestamp": "1640049459",
            "signature": "YQvl1dWkN6MrHQ8xGwEQndVo2QdPSzc6EqLJslzNjy4%3D",
            "code": "test"
        }
    }
```

This is my code right now:

```
url = "https://api.ordergroove.com/customer/update_customer"

headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
}

body = """
    update_request={{
         "id": "f07de0a44c2911ea8fb2bc764e10b970",
         "user": {
             "timestamp": "1640049459",
             "signature": "YQvl1dWkN6MrHQ8xGwEQndVo2QdPSzc6EqLJslzNjy4%3D",
             "code": "test"
         }
     }}
"""

#Send and print response
response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
```

If I run this in Postman though it works just fine:
[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LPJn.png)

Comment: What's wrong with the code  you posted here...?

Comment: Also, what kind of API is this that they accept non-standard JSON as a valid POST body?

Comment: that doesnt seem like the right thing to post...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests

url = "https://46463d29-e52d-4bb9-bdda-68f0dfd7d06d.mock.pstmn.io/test"

payload = " update_request={{\r\n         \"id\": \"f07de0a44c2911ea8fb2bc764e10b970\",\r\n         \"user\": {\r\n             \"timestamp\": \"1640049459\",\r\n             \"signature\": \"YQvl1dWkN6MrHQ8xGwEQndVo2QdPSzc6EqLJslzNjy4%3D\",\r\n             \"code\": \"test\"\r\n         }\r\n     }}"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

you can geenrate the code form postman itself

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!! This was exactly what I needed, I had no idea I could get the code snippet directly from Postman. The payload structure was so wonky I didn't know how to structure it. This worked great though.

Answer (score 1):

maybe ... and this is a big maybe

```
url = "https://api.ordergroove.com/customer/update_customer"


data = {"update_request":{
     "id": "f07de0a44c2911ea8fb2bc764e10b970",
     "user": {
         "timestamp": "1640049459",
         "signature": "YQvl1dWkN6MrHQ8xGwEQndVo2QdPSzc6EqLJslzNjy4%3D",
         "code": "test"
     }
   }
}

requests.post(url,json=data)
```

might work ...

Answer (score 0):

In your case, your content-type specifies JSON, which is a common body type, so requests added a completely different way to send a json body (using the json parameter) by specifying json=body. Body is another dictionary type, which is then parsed into a string for you and sent with the request. Both x-www-form encoded and json are common body types that are essentially dictionaries, so they can be mixed up often but are NOT interchangeable.

```
data = {
"update_request":{
     "id": "f07de0a44c2911ea8fb2bc764e10b970",
     "user": {
         "timestamp": "1640049459",
         "signature": "YQvl1dWkN6MrHQ8xGwEQndVo2QdPSzc6EqLJslzNjy4%3D",
         "code": "test"
     }
   }
}

response = requests.post(url,json=data)#data=body for x-www-urlencoded form data, json=body for content-type json
```

Requests in this case will automatically add the content-type json header and format the dictionary into a string for you correctly, instead of sending the content-type x-www-form encoded content-type header if you were to put body=data

You are still able to use raw json data for requests by just passing in json=raw_data, raw data being a string. This is frowned upon since if there is any formatting issues, servers will likely not be able to read your request body. No reason to do that when you can pass in a python dictionary object as previously shown, and requests parses it into a string for you!